# How to get the item id in sqlite database with the help of object

Tags: android, sqlite

I have custom adapter and in the layout of listview there is an delete button which should delete that item from listview and database also. For removing item from listview i have used myList.remove(position) . But simultaneously i should delete that item from database too. I have created a method delete item in my databasehandler class which takes the parameter of object.

```
public void deleteItem(Object item)
{

    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DataConstants.table_name, DataConstants.id_name + "=?", new String[]{*});//add item id in database here


}
```

What should i keep in place of astrick so that i can get item from database and it will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any u unique place of astrick. but best best way you should put primary key or row id here;
like

```
db.delete(DataConstants.table_name, DataConstants.id_name + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(1)});
```

Comment: so my question was that how can i get the primary key value of 1 of that item. I can pass that item in form of object. How to i retrive the primary key value of that object.

Comment: take value in object in adapter and call on button click simple . accept if answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should have your objects array stored in your `ListView` adapter, and thus, you can retrieve every item ID using : `myAdapter.getItem(position).getID()`. Where `getID()` is a getter method you should define in your `Item` class.

Then you can remove the corresponding record in database, by doing something like this : `mDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id=" + id, null);`

Let me know if you need any further details about this answer.

**UPDATE :**

For example, you have this class of items you'll pass later to your `ListView` adapter :

```
public class MyItem {
    // Attributes
    private int mID;
    private String mName;
    private String mDescription;

    // Constructor
    public MyItem(int id, String name, String description) {
        mID = id;
        mName = name;
        mDescription = description;
    }

    /* Get the ID of Item object outside this class
       (for example : in ListView Activity) */
    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    /*
    .
    . Some other useful code may be
    .
    */
}
```

Comment: yeah can you please give me the code for that getter method? I am unable to use getId() method.

Comment: You have to implement it yourself in your entity class, please see my answer, I updated it for you.

Answer (score 0):

its simple first get the name on the listview.
getallrows and find one that contains that name in name colum.
getId of that column..

Comment: List<GestureModel> gest = db.getAllgestures();
        int id = 0;
        for(GestureModel gst: gest)
        {
            if(gst.getGesturename().equals(name))
            {
               id=gst.getId();
                break;
            }
        }
GestureModel one = db.getGesture(id);
        db.deletegesture(one);